# Node js get image from web and convert it into an array of byte values

Tags: javascript, node.js

What other libraries i can use with `request` so I can convert it to an array of bytes?

```
var request = require('request');
request('https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/men/81.jpg', function (error, response, body) {
  if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {

  }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

ImageMagic, which has several [3rd party JS SDKs](https://github.com/aheckmann/gm), would work.